# All Products showing in one row when i use short code wordPress

Tags: plugins

Ecommerce product catalog not showing product in a row.
I am putting short code to show products.
when i put my short to show products its show products list in one row.
i want to show products in 3 row.
my short code is

```
<h4>Southern Pepper Curry​</h4>
[show_products per_column="2"  per_row="2" category="89" archive_template="morden"   ]
```

i am using per_row="2" means i want to show products two in each row also how can i give pagination.
i have also change in Ecommerce product catalog plugin setting with 2 product per row but effect on my site.